# How to combine two shaders into one shader in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I spent a lot of time in Unity to combine two shaders into one, but nothing come out. Never encountered with Cg/HLSL

In Unity Project I want to combine two shaders into one shader to get both of their functionality (except fog from second shader). 
First shader is for lighting and texture color with removing transparent, the other shader is for underwater caustic and fog. How do I combine?

First shader

```
Shader "Nature/Tree Soft Occlusion Leaves" {
Properties {
    _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _MainTex ("Main Texture", 2D) = "white" {  }
    _Cutoff ("Alpha cutoff", Range(0.25,0.9)) = 0.5
    _BaseLight ("Base Light", Range(0, 1)) = 0.35
    _AO ("Amb. Occlusion", Range(0, 10)) = 2.4
    _Occlusion ("Dir Occlusion", Range(0, 20)) = 7.5

    // These are here only to provide default values
    [HideInInspector] _TreeInstanceColor ("TreeInstanceColor", Vector) = (1,1,1,1)
    [HideInInspector] _TreeInstanceScale ("TreeInstanceScale", Vector) = (1,1,1,1)
    [HideInInspector] _SquashAmount ("Squash", Float) = 1
}

SubShader {
    Tags {
        "Queue" = "AlphaTest"
        "IgnoreProjector"="True"
        "RenderType" = "TreeTransparentCutout"
        "DisableBatching"="True"
    }
    Cull Off
    ColorMask RGB

    Pass {
        Lighting On

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex leaves
        #pragma fragment frag
        #pragma multi_compile_fog
        #include "UnityBuiltin2xTreeLibrary.cginc"

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        fixed _Cutoff;

        fixed4 frag(v2f input) : SV_Target
        {
            fixed4 c = tex2D( _MainTex, input.uv.xy);
            c.rgb *= input.color.rgb;

            clip (c.a - _Cutoff);
            UNITY_APPLY_FOG(input.fogCoord, c);
            return c;
        }
        ENDCG
    }

    Pass {
        Name "ShadowCaster"
        Tags { "LightMode" = "ShadowCaster" }

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #pragma multi_compile_shadowcaster
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"
        #include "TerrainEngine.cginc"

        struct v2f {
            V2F_SHADOW_CASTER;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD1;
            UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
        };

        struct appdata {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float3 normal : NORMAL;
            fixed4 color : COLOR;
            float4 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
        };
        v2f vert( appdata v )
        {
            v2f o;
            UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(v);
            UNITY_INITIALIZE_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(o);
            TerrainAnimateTree(v.vertex, v.color.w);
            TRANSFER_SHADOW_CASTER_NORMALOFFSET(o)
            o.uv = v.texcoord;
            return o;
        }

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        fixed _Cutoff;

        float4 frag( v2f i ) : SV_Target
        {
            fixed4 texcol = tex2D( _MainTex, i.uv );
            clip( texcol.a - _Cutoff );
            SHADOW_CASTER_FRAGMENT(i)
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}

// This subshader is never actually used, but is only kept so
// that the tree mesh still assumes that normals are needed
// at build time (due to Lighting On in the pass). The subshader
// above does not actually use normals, so they are stripped out.
// We want to keep normals for backwards compatibility with Unity 4.2
// and earlier.
SubShader {
    Tags {
        "Queue" = "AlphaTest"
        "IgnoreProjector"="True"
        "RenderType" = "TransparentCutout"
    }
    Cull Off
    ColorMask RGB
    Pass {
        Tags { "LightMode" = "Vertex" }
        AlphaTest GEqual [_Cutoff]
        Lighting On
        Material {
            Diffuse [_Color]
            Ambient [_Color]
        }
        SetTexture [_MainTex] { combine primary * texture DOUBLE, texture }
    }
}

Dependency "BillboardShader" = "Hidden/Nature/Tree Soft Occlusion Leaves Rendertex"
Fallback Off}
```

Second Shader

```
Shader "Underwater/Mobile"{
Properties
{
    _MainTex("Main Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    [Header(Caustics)]
    _Caustics("Caustics Texture (RGBA)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _CausticsCoord("Tiling(XY) Offset(ZW) - Overrides texture coords", Vector) = (0.5,0.5,0,0)
    _CausticsSpeed("Speed", Float) = 1
    _CausticsBoost("Boost", Range(0,1)) = 0
    _CausticsIntensity0("Intensity A", Range(0, 1)) = 1
    _CausticsIntensity1("Intensity B", Range(0, 1)) = 0
    _CausticsPosition0("Position A (World Y)", Float) = 2
    _CausticsPosition1("Position B (World Y)", Float) = 4
    [Header(Fog)]
    _FogColor0("Color A", Color) = (0.004, 0.271, 0.302, 1)
    _FogColor1("Color B", Color) = (0.004, 0.271, 0.302, 1)
    _FogIntensity0("Intensity A", Range(0, 1)) = 1
    _FogIntensity1("Intensity B", Range(0, 1)) = 1
    _FogPosition0("Position A (World Y)", Float) = 0
    _FogPosition1("Position B (World Y)", Float) = 6
    _FogStart("Start", Float) = 0
    _FogEnd("End", Float) = 15
    [HideInInspector]
    _Animation("Animation", Float) = 0
}

SubShader
{
    Tags{ "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
    LOD 200

    CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf CustomLambert nofog noambient noforwardadd exclude_path:deferred exclude_path:prepass
        #pragma multi_compile SHADER_CONTROL SCRIPT_CONTROL
        #pragma target 3.0

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        sampler2D _Caustics;
        float4 _CausticsCoord;
        fixed _CausticsSpeed;
        fixed _CausticsBoost;
        fixed _CausticsIntensity0;
        fixed _CausticsIntensity1;
        fixed _CausticsPosition0;
        fixed _CausticsPosition1;
        fixed3 _FogColor0;
        fixed3 _FogColor1;
        uniform fixed _FogIntensity0;
        uniform fixed _FogIntensity1;
        uniform fixed _FogPosition0;
        uniform fixed _FogPosition1;
        uniform half _FogStart;
        uniform half _FogEnd;

        #ifdef SCRIPT_CONTROL
        fixed _Animation;
        #endif

        struct SurfaceOutputCustom
        {
            fixed3 Albedo;
            fixed3 Normal;
            fixed3 Emission;
            half Specular;
            fixed Gloss;
            fixed Alpha;
            fixed3 worldPos;
            fixed3 worldNormal;
        };

        half4 LightingCustomLambert( SurfaceOutputCustom s, half3 lightDir, half atten )
        {
            half diffuseReflection = dot(s.Normal, lightDir);

            float dist = distance(_WorldSpaceCameraPos, s.worldPos);

            fixed mixed = clamp((s.worldPos.y - _FogPosition0) / (_FogPosition1 - _FogPosition0), 0, 1);
            fixed3 fogColor = lerp(_FogColor0 * _FogIntensity0, _FogColor1 * _FogIntensity1, mixed);

            mixed = lerp(_FogIntensity0, _FogIntensity1, mixed);
            mixed = saturate((_FogStart - dist) / (_FogStart - _FogEnd)) * mixed;

            #ifdef DIRECTIONAL
            fogColor = fogColor * mixed;
            #else
            fogColor = fogColor * mixed * atten;
            #endif

            fixed lightColor = diffuseReflection * atten * (1 - mixed);

            #ifdef SCRIPT_CONTROL
            fixed4 caustics0 = tex2D(_Caustics, s.worldPos.zx * _CausticsCoord.xy + float2(_Animation, 0));
            fixed4 caustics1 = tex2D(_Caustics, s.worldPos.zx * _CausticsCoord.xy + float2(-_Animation, 0));
            fixed4 caustics2 = tex2D(_Caustics, s.worldPos.zx * _CausticsCoord.xy + float2(0, _Animation));
            fixed4 caustics3 = tex2D(_Caustics, s.worldPos.zx * _CausticsCoord.xy + float2(0, -_Animation));
            #else
            fixed4 caustics0 = tex2D(_Caustics, s.worldPos.zx * _CausticsCoord.xy + float2(_CausticsCoord.z + (_Time.x * _CausticsSpeed), _CausticsCoord.w));
            fixed4 caustics1 = tex2D(_Caustics, s.worldPos.zx * _CausticsCoord.xy + float2(_CausticsCoord.z - (_Time.x * _CausticsSpeed), _CausticsCoord.w));
            fixed4 caustics2 = tex2D(_Caustics, s.worldPos.zx * _CausticsCoord.xy + float2(_CausticsCoord.z, _CausticsCoord.w + (_Time.x * _CausticsSpeed)));
            fixed4 caustics3 = tex2D(_Caustics, s.worldPos.zx * _CausticsCoord.xy + float2(_CausticsCoord.z, _CausticsCoord.w - (_Time.x * _CausticsSpeed)));
            #endif

            fixed3 caustics = ((saturate(caustics0.r + caustics1.g + caustics2.b + caustics3.a) * (_CausticsBoost + 1)) + _CausticsBoost);

            fixed causticsIntensity = clamp((s.worldPos.y - _CausticsPosition0) / (_CausticsPosition1 - _CausticsPosition0), 0, 1);
            causticsIntensity = lerp(_CausticsIntensity0, _CausticsIntensity1, causticsIntensity);

            fixed3 light = lightColor * _LightColor0;

            #ifdef DIRECTIONAL
            fixed3 ambient = ShadeSH9(half4(s.worldNormal, 1)) * (1 - mixed);
            light = lerp(light, light * caustics, causticsIntensity);
            #else
            fixed3 ambient = (ShadeSH9(half4(s.worldNormal, 1)) * (1 - mixed)) * atten;
            #endif

            ambient = lerp(ambient, ambient * caustics, causticsIntensity);

            half4 c;

            c.rgb = s.Albedo * ( light + ambient ) + fogColor;
            c.a = s.Alpha;

            return c;
        }

        struct Input
        {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
            float3 worldPos;
            float3 worldNormal;
        };

        void surf( Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputCustom o)
        {
            o.worldPos = IN.worldPos;
            o.worldNormal = IN.worldNormal;
            o.Albedo = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex).rgb;
        }
    ENDCG

}

FallBack "Underwater/Mobile Fast"}
```

Comment: One of them is a fragment shader, the other is a surface shader. You're not going to be able to combine these easily, if at all.